# How setup WildFly 10 to automatic restart JVM after crash?

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-10, wildfly-cluster

Please help, how to setup WildFly 10 for automatic restart after a JVM crash.

We use the JNI interface for native applications and we has a periodicly crash JVM.
Use full-ha and ha modes does't work. Аfter JVM-crash, we should manually start server.

Comment: In 2011, it was not possible - https://developer.jboss.org/thread/173934

Comment: You'd have to write some kind of script at the OS level. If the JVM crashes there's not much WildFly can do.

Answer (score 0):

You might have found a solution but to help those who come later and don't mind using [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/), then I just setup wildfly9 and think the same can be done for wildfly10 or any other service. Here is my conf file:

```
[program:wildfly]
command=/home/engine/wildfly9/bin/standalone.sh -Djboss.server.base.dir=/home/engine/wildfly9/standalone/ -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=20000 -Djboss.node.name=node1 --server-config=engine.xml
stdout_logfile=/var/log/wildfly/engine.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/wildfly/engine_error.log
autorestart=true
autostart=true
user=engine
directory=/home/engine
stopasgroup=true
```

Hope it helps.